# Python String Difficulties

Tags: python, string

Im new to python and we just started working on strings.  Here is a problem I am having some difficulty with.

You are given a long string:

```
Justin$Calculus$90$Java$85$Python88$
Taylor$Calculus$73$Java$95$Python86$
Drew$Calculus$80$Java$75$Python94$
```

The string has three lines. It contains three students’ scores of three courses. Write a function `findScore(student, subject)`. When you call the function such as `findScore(‘Drew’,’Java’)`, the function prints `“Drew got 75 of the course Java.”` In addition to the function `findScore(student, subject)`, you can write other functions. All the functions are inside one program.

I was thinking about doing something like this, but have hit a wall and just can get anywhere. I don't have much experience in python, so theres probably a way better way to do it. Please help.

```
def findScore(student,subject):
  for i in string.split('$'):
    if student == Justin and subject == Calculus:
      JCalscore=90
    if student == Justin and subject == Java:
      JJavscore=85
    if student == Justin and subjext == Python:
      JPytscore=88
```

Comment: @Tim It's funny, because the sample string is _exactly the same_.

Comment: @rsegal What's funnier is that the duplicate question was closed because it was *unlikely to help any future visitors*.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're happy to assist you with any programming issues you might have. However, we're not a homework resource. Your university undoubtedly has those. Since this question asks for help with homework, you're not going to get 'plug-and-play' sorts of answers. Instead, we'll prod you in the right direction by pointing out facts that you've given us, and asking leading questions.

Further, it seems your question is a duplicate. You're expected to have done serious looking before posing a question before us.

First, it seems like your information is split by a space/newline for each student. It seems like each of those blocks contains the information for 1 person, so it might make sense to split along those lines. If you've gotten to `classes` in your course, this might be a good place to consider a way to store *the same kinds of information* with *different values*. Otherwise, you might consider other data types such as `lists`, `sets`, or `dictionaries`.

It seems like you want to store *values* that you can look up by their *names*. Python's built-in 'dict' type and 'class' system are very good at this! Alternatively, tuples of course names and grades in a list could easily perform the same task.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `string.split('$')` you're splitting the entire string, not just one line. Also, when you say `student == Justin` or `subject == Calculus` python is trying to find a variable named `Justin` or `Calculus`.

What I would suggest is using the interactive python interpreter to try these things out.

```
   >>> a = '''
   ... Jstin$Calculus$90$Java$85$Python88$
   ... Taylor$Calculus$73$Java$95$Python86$
   ... Drew$Calculus$80$Java$75$Python94$
   ... '''

   >>> a.split('$')
   ['\nJustin', 'Calculus', '90', 'Java', '85', 'Python88', '\nTaylor', 'Calculus',
  '73', 'Java', '95', 'Python86', '\nDrew', 'Calculus', '80', 'Java', '75', 'Pyth
on94', '\n']
   >>> b = 'Justin'
   >>> if b == Justin:
   ...  print 'yes'
   ...
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  NameError: name 'Justin' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

string = '''
Justin$Calculus$90$Java$85$Python88$
Taylor$Calculus$73$Java$95$Python86$
Drew$Calculus$80$Java$75$Python94$
'''

def findScore(student,subject) :
    global string
    students = [i for i in string.split('\n') if i]    # non-empty strings only
    for i in students :
        parts = i.split('$')
        if parts[0] == student :
            for j in range(1,len(parts),2) :
                if parts[j] == subject :
                    print student, 'got', parts[j+1], 'in', parts[j]

findScore( 'Justin', 'Java' )
```

Comment: Why process the string every time? It would make more sense to process it once and store it in an appropriate data structure, so the lookup can be completed in constant time.

Comment: i'm afraid he won't be able to explain data structures to his teacher yet